# Whether there is a shortcut key method to go back file in PyCharm?

Tags: pycharm

In the PyCharm, I can use Command + left click the `Album` class:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

To hop over to the Album class file detail easily:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

But whether there is a shortcut key method to go back ?

Comment: Most likely - Ctrl + Tab will do what you want to do but it isn't a direct correlation

Comment: Try the mac equivalent to Ctrl+Alt+Left

Comment: @Sayse Thank you, you gives me the answer.

Comment: I don't know if there exist such short command. If it opens a new tab, you could just do Cmd+w, which closes the tab and brings you back to the latest file and location, or Ctrl+Left/Right to go back to your file. You could also use Cmd+shift+backspace, which takes you back to the last place you made an edit.